# Creating a custom GridView that has text in the first column and images in the others

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a custom `GridView` for Android that always has text in the first column and reserves the others for images. For example:

```
Text Text  Text 
Text Image Image
Text Image Image
Text Image Image
Text Image Image
     .....
     .....
Text Image Image
```

I don't know if this is possible or not. If it is possible, how should I be implementing it?

Comment: Have you tried it or do you expect someone to give you the complete code?  If GridView doesn't work, there is GridLayout in later API versions.

Comment: I just new to work with grid, so I have see many example on the internet, just show about the custom gridview that inflate each item from a layout. so that why I ask that question to have some idea. And Don tell me I know that no one will write me a complete code.

Comment: Can I ask why on earth this question has been edited to completely change the scope of the question? My answer doesn't even apply now, so far to the point it looks completely wrong. There is not even any remnants left of what was initially being asked? It was asked how to create a custom GridView with a specific layout....

Answer (score 1):

Very possible. You just have to think about what you want to do, where it applies, then add in the code to the appropriate areas.

For example:

**Step 1: Figure out / know how many columns**
Either get how many columns your `GridView` currently has at runtime by the appropriate member function call ([GridView.getNumColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#getNumColumns%28%29) - note you must be >= API level 11 to use this call). Otherwise [GridView.setNumColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setNumColumns%28int%29) will need to be done in the setup. A last option is to figure out what the number of columns should be, and set this in `onMeasure` or similar `Overrides`.

**Step 2: Write your getView code**
In your code for `getView` in the adapter you choose, you should be able to do simple math to figure out what to do. For example:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Either have numOfColumns saved as a global variable or get it here depending on your method

    // Create your view for the item
    View ret;

    if (position < numOfColumns || position % numOfColumns == 0) { 
        // Aka if first row OR if first column
        TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);

        // Do all your textview formatting etc etc....

        ret = tv;
    } else {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(mContext);

        // Do all your imageview layout stuff etc etc....

        ret = iv;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Note: This is purely just your brainstorming / thinking out loud done for you to get you started. You are missing things like (a clever way to memory optimize for recycling views with different types of `Views` if your `GridView` will scroll). You could also consider creating a custom layout and just using that as your view and modifying it as necessary with the above selection code.

So to answer your question, **yes** it is possible.

Comment: thank that a great idea for me, I will try this, but as I see it seems work well from your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this tutorial for Custom Grid View

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

```
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                   getApplicationContext(),
                   ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label))
                   .getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });




public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private final String[] mobileValues;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from mobile.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);

        // set value into textview
        TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
        textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);

        // set image based on selected text
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

        String mobile = mobileValues[position];

        if (mobile.equals("Windows")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.windows_logo);
        } else if (mobile.equals("iOS")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ios_logo);
        } else if (mobile.equals("Blackberry")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blackberry_logo);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_logo);
        }

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mobileValues.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

}
```